# Why is the served index.html not updated?

Tags: github-pages

Inspect http://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/.  It's an 8917-octet source from 8 August 2013.  If I examine https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/gh-pages/index.html though, I find 9077 bytes from today, 20 December 2013.  What do I do to convince GH to serve up the latest source of `gh-pages/index.html`, rather than the one from August?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the commits under https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/tree/gh-pages, and comparing the changes made with the site at http://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/, it seems that the changes have been pushed correctly to the site, and the site is up to date.

The changes made in commit f4a18d546aa9170db3284ce3a6a58ad9a927d9ff can be found on line 130 under "Remarks on GitHub".

Comment: No.  That is, while I appreciate the intent of what you wrote, it seems to me to answer something different from what I asked.  Rather than pursue what psgs appears to have said about what he thinks I need about ...  I'll just provide my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I quote (slightly re-formatted) from private e-mail a GitHub staffer sent me: "Any GitHub user who wants to trigger page builds must have a verified email address. You can verify your email address [here](https://github.com/settings/emails).

Once you've verified your email address, future pushes of the gh-pages branch will trigger page builds."

That did it: I verified a couple of e-mail addresses, pushed another version, and then http://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/ updated to my latest changes.